# ReactJS: How to export a component that destructures into more components

Tags: reactjs, import, export

I'm trying to replicate an example where I don't have the code in which they export a component but also destructure it. Not sure how it's done since if you destructure it, then it's an object, but then how can it also be a component?

```js
import { Card } from 'example-npm-project';
const { Header, Content, Divider } = Card;
```

and then they use it like this...

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Card.Header>
      </Card.Header>
    </Card>
  )
}
```

or they can just use the Header component `<Header>` directly since they destructured it.

My best guess is to export it somehow like this but the Card component won't actually be a component... unless I'm missing something...

index.js

```js
import { Header } from "./Header"
import { Content } from "./Content"
import { Divider } from "./Divider"

export const Card = { Header, Content, Divider }; // ???
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```js
import { Card } from "./Card"
import { Header } from "./Header"
import { Content } from "./Content"
import { Divider } from "./Divider"

export { Card };
Card.Header = Header;
Card.Content = Content;
Card.Divider = Divider;
```